# xz compression install on centos

Tags: linux, centos, yum

Any installation or update using yum command I ended up error: Error: xz compression not available. On website I read that Python library is missing. When you try to install a library (sudo yum update pyliblzma) again failed with error. Do not know how? Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

This problem comes if you installed a wrong epel release on your machine. If so, then you need to remove the epel release by

```
yum remove epel-release
```

Sometimes that is not enough, you need to remove the cache as well by:

```
rm -rf /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/epel
```

Then you can install the epel-release again

```
yum -y install epel-release
```

Comment: `yum clean all` is doing great for cleaning the cache

Answer (score 4):

You need install the EPEL repository by downloading the appropriate RPM package for your system and installing it. For example, for CentOS and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.x:

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

sudo rpm -Uvh epel-release-6*.rpm
```

If you get a File Not Found error message when trying to download the package, the version number might have changed. You can access the latest version of the RPM installer from the Fedora EPEL wiki page. The wiki page also includes additional instructions for Red Hat Network subscribers who are installing the EPEL repository.

Finally, install the Python library:

```
yum install pyliblzma
```

This works perfecly in my CentOS 6.x.

Comment: It is not just about centos 6. I was getting "xz compression not available" with epel on centos 7 docker container. Installing pyliblzma solved the issue.

Comment: Has nothing to do with "xz compression not available".

Comment: The key fix for me on my RHEL 6 system was to install the Python library

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution on this page of stackexchange, working in CentOS 6.X:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314756

```
sudo rpm -e epel-release-7-5.noarch

wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

sudo yum clean all

sudo rpmdb -v --rebuilddb

sudo yum -y install libselinux-python
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also suffering from this issue..

If you are installing packages but it is already available on your system.
Remove existing packages and then try to install new.

It will work properly...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by installing **pyliblzma** using rpm instead of yum as yum is not working.

Find **pyliblzma** rpm package according to your architecture and install it using the command.

**rpm -Uvh pyliblzma-version-release.architecture.rpm**

I used the following command to install **pyliblzma** for my 64 bit Redhat 6.8 machine. Please check URL in the command and make changes accordingly.

**rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/pyliblzma-0.5.3-3.el6.x86_64.rpm**

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was caused by missing modules in python's site-packages directory. Here's what I did:

```
$ rpm -Va
```

to get a list of all files belonging to all rpms that do not verify. I got a bunch of messages about missing modules:

```
missing     /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/...
```

Luckily, I had an identical CentOS version elsewhere with all these packages present, so I just copied them over and ran

```
$ rpmdb -v --rebuilddb
```

to rebuild rpm database.